# Block function as a parameter of other block functions?

Tags: smarty

I have on question about Smarty 3. I want to put block function as a parameter of other block function. Here's an example:

```
{func param={otherfunc}Second block{/otherfunc}}First block{/func}
```

This of course is not working, but I can't find a way to make it work.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help at Smarty forums, correct code would be:

```
{func param="{otherfunc}Second block{/otherfunc}"}First block{/func}
```